# Aggregate daily data to weekly level in SQL: Tuesday to Monday being a week

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, aggregate

I have a daily level Sales data and I want to aggregate it to weekly level in SQL server.

Start of any week should be Tuesday and End being Monday respectively

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post a bit more about what you've tried.  Maybe give us some sample code and problems you are having.  That being said please see below.  Without seeing your solutions specifics there's a lot of different approaches to this.

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de906/3/1)

```
SET DATEFIRST 2;

DECLARE @SalesData TABLE    (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), SalesDate DATETIME, Price MONEY)
INSERT INTO @SalesData (SalesDate,Price) VALUES
    ('1/1/2013',12.00),
    ('1/2/2013',14.00),
    ('1/3/2013',11.28),
    ('5/3/2013',11.64),
    ('5/3/2013',18.00)

;WITH
SalesInfo AS
(
    SELECT  sd.id,
          YEAR(sd.SalesDate) AS TheYear,
          DATEPART(week,sd.SalesDate) AS TheWeek
    FROM      @SalesData sd
)
SELECT  SI.TheYear,
       SI.TheWeek,
       SUM(SD.Price) AS TotalForWeek
FROM       @SalesData AS SD
       INNER JOIN SalesInfo AS SI ON (SD.ID = SI.ID)
GROUP BY      SI.TheYear,SI.TheWeek


SET DATEFIRST 7
```

[DATEFIRST MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)